# FireFox Save Image on local drive

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

The following code won't work in FireFox. I'm trying to save a canvas (image) locally:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasData");
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
link.download = filename + ".png";
link.click();
```

It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work in Firefox you simply need to create a MouseEvent and dispatch it on the link object (this will also work for Chrome, but not in IE which doesn't support the `download` attribute in any case..):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasData");
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
link.download = filename + ".png";

// create a mouse event
var event = new MouseEvent('click');

// dispatching it will open a save as dialog in FF
link.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/egbuy0a8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Attempts to save a file to the user's local drive without user confirmation are security risks and will likely be prevented in future versions of Chrome.

In Firefox (and Chrome) the user can right-click to save the canvas as an image to their local drive. Just let your users know this is an option.

If you want something more automatic then check out the `FileSaver` script by Eli Grey which does a nice job of automatically saving the canvas to local drive--with user's confirmation, of course: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js